# Facebook Login with Sentry, A password is required for user [email], none given

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-4

I'm trying to allow users to login using facebook but my user management is based on sentry
as you know if you connect from facebook, you wont need a password unless you are creating a account normally. Is there a way to tell sentry(http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4) that this is a facebook login and it doesnt require a "password"

I tried giving the account a temp password but i receive 
A hasher has not been provided for the user , even when i hash it.

Any advice on this?

I'm also using http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/ as a guide

```
Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
$code = Input::get('code');
if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

$me = $facebook->api('/me');

$profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
if (empty($profile)) {

    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'];
    $user->email = $me['email'];
    $user->photo = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$me['username'].'/picture?type=large';

    $user->save();

    $profile = new Profile();
    $profile->uid = $uid;
    $profile->username = $me['username'];
    $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);
}

$profile->access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$profile->save();

$user = $profile->user;

Auth::login($user);

return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Logged in with Facebook');
```

});

Comment: Did you mention Sentry?

Comment: Yes, @kJamesy http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4

Comment: You did but there is nowhere in your code where sentry is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at doing something similar, and was thinking of using the facebook uid as the password. Would this not work?

Edit:
I can confirm the following works for me:

```
function callback()
{
    $code = Input::get('code');
    if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    //dd($me);

    //Check if user profile exists
    $profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
    if (empty($profile)) {

        // Create the user
        $user = Sentry::createUser(array(
            'email'      => $me['email'],
            'password'   => $uid,
            'first_name' => $me['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $me['last_name'],
            'photo'      =>  'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$me['username'].'/picture?type=large',
            'activated'  => 1
        ));

        // Find the group using the group id
        $registered = Sentry::findGroupById(2);
        // Assign the group to the user
        $user->addGroup($registered);

        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->uid = $uid;
        $profile->username = $me['username'];
        $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);
    }

    $profile->access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $profile->save();

    $user = $profile->user;
    Sentry::login($user, false);
    $user = Sentry::getUser();

    echo $user->first_name . " logged in.";
    //return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Logged in with Facebook');
}
```

Also note that you'll need customize the model sentry uses using this method (http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=48274#p48274) in order to specify the relationship with profiles

Comment: This code isn't working any more:
$profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);

can you visit my question here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981733/sentry-2-facebook-oauth-on-laravel-says-call-to-undefined-method-profile

Answer (score 3):

I think that when you create the user you need to use Sentry::createUser()

```
$user = Sentry::createUser(array(
    'name'     => $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'],
    'email'    => $me['email'],
    'password' => 'test',
    'photo'    => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$me['username'].'/picture?type=large',
));
```

And then use **Sentry::login($user, false);** to force a login for the user without a password.

You probably also want to put something in the password field other than test if you also have a regular non-facebook login.

Also you may have to activate the user depending on what your plans were with that email:

```
//You could email this to the user from here.
$activationCode = $user->getActivationCode();

//OR just activate immediately. 
$user->attemptActivation($activationCode);
```

Comment: it says Method [createUser] is not supported by Sentry or no User has been set on Sentry to access shortcut method. when i do that

Comment: and btw, i'm doing it in routes.php

Comment: Does Sentry::findAllUsers(); throw a similar error? Have you double checked that you followed the install procedure on Sentry2? http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4