# Facebook authentication + register user to database

Tags: facebook, backbone.js, laravel-4, facebook-authentication

I'm building a Javascript application with Backbone, and implemented a restful interface for the user authentication with Laravel4 as a backend (using Laravel's authentication mechanism).
All works nice and smooth.

I created a basic demo that allows the user to log in using their Facebook account.
In order to do this, I used the Facebook SDK for JS (web).

What I don't understand is how I can implement the following:
The user logs in the first time with his/her Facebook account, and the user data should be stored in my database automagically (ie email, first name, last name, gender, birthdate).
Imagine that the user decides to remove his Facebook account, (s)he may assume that (s)he'll be still able to log in to my web application using the default login screen of my own application.

But it is obviously not possible to upload their Facebook password to have it handled by Laravel's authentication.
So what is the most common solution to handle this problem?

Comment: Since you've already stored the user's email and profile in your DB when they login with FB for the first time, even when they decided not using FB anymore, you could implement something like 'forget password' feature where you sent a auto-gen password to their email for them to login to your system and then change it later.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that could be useful. Perhaps I should manage the logic myself and create a flag in the user table that represents a status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common solution to provide a Facebook Login and re-use Facebook account details in your own login system is, to use a Laravel library like Sentry, which supports OAuth2(http://oauth.net/2/).

Because you are forcing a Sentry::login($user, false); for the user without a password, you might want to generate a password field to have a regular non-facebook login.
After a successful login to your website with OAuth2 against FB, you simply store the client-secret, log the user into your system, fetch the FB infos you need and send an email with a generated PW for direct login to your application.
Email: "Thank you for registering to this website via Facebook. Your PW is ....".

As pointed out by @har2vey, it's the same functionality as provided by the "resend my password" feature, but directly send after login via OAuth and not on user request.

A Sentry example is already on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511907/1163786

Sidenote:
It's unfair towards those who take the time to answer, if you simply delete your questions.
I'm refering to [switch-profiles-on-the-client-and-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794812/switch-profiles-on-the-client-and-server). The answer could be useful to others aswell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your comment: I deleted the previous question deliberately, because a misleading logic error was present in the (long) question itself. Moreover, my question was related to switching full profiles, while your answer contained information about a role management system, which on itself was unrelated and can therefore extensively be found in rbac related questions and Google. No offense intended, but removing the question seemed to have been the best solution and I'm sorry for your time.