# Sentry 2 Facebook Oauth On Laravel says Call to undefined method ::profile()

Tags: php, laravel-4, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, cartalyst-sentry

I am using Laravel 4.1, and using `facebook/php-sdk` with sentry actually it's derived from this questions answer:
[Facebook Login with Sentry, A password is required for user [email], none given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768103/facebook-login-with-sentry-a-password-is-required-for-user-email-none-given)

This code isn't working any more:

```
    $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);
```

throws this error:
[image]

How to resolve it?

route for that is available here [Route code](http://laravel.io/bin/Loxkz)

My models are as bellows:

Profile model:

```
<?php

class Profile extends \Eloquent {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

User model contains:

```
public function profiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Profile');
}
```

Comment: Have you created the hasMany relation (profiles method) in User model ?

Comment: yes let me update my question with the model's codes

Comment: Do you customize the model sentry using this method (http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=48274#p48274) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the comments :

> Do you customize the model sentry using this method http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=48274#p48274 ? –  user1279647